# How to sort teams by summarized score in SQL? (two columns sorting with SUM())

Tags: mysql, sorting

`Playerbase` have 3 columns: `PlrName`, `TeamTag`, `Score`
I need to sort players grouping them by `TeamTag`. And put teams with best summarized score above.

So want to figure out what query will help make this:

```
PlrName|TeamTag|Score        PlrName|TeamTag|Score
-------------------------------------------------------
Player1|TeamThr|0            Player6|TeamThr|9  \
Player2|TeamTwo|2            Player1|TeamThr|0   > 9
Player3|TeamOne|4            Player4|TeamThr|0  /
Player4|TeamThr|0            Player5|TeamOne|4  \
Player5|TeamOne|4  became->  Player3|TeamOne|4   > 8
Player6|TeamThr|9            Player8|TeamOne|0  /
Player7|TeamTwo|2            Player2|TeamTwo|2  \
Player8|TeamOne|0            Player7|TeamTwo|2   > 6
Player9|TeamTwo|2            Player9|TeamTwo|2  /
```

added:
With this query i can get an array(?) of `TeamTag`'s ordered by team score:

`SELECT TeamTag FROM Playerbase GROUP BY team ORDER BY SUM(Score) DESC`

..can I sort then `PlayerBase` using this "array"? Prefably within one query :)
Also i need to get full lines (using *), not only three fields.

Answer (score 1):

If your dbms doesn't support window functions (any MySQL version below 8.0):

```
SELECT PlrName, TeamTag, Score FROM table a
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT PlrName, TeamTag, Score ,SUM(score) ts FROM table GROUP BY TeamTag) b 
ON a.TeamTag=b.TeamTag
ORDER BY b.ts DESC, a.TeamTag, score DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
; with cte as (
select  TeamTag, sum(Score) as Sum
from tablename)
select t.PlrName, t.teamtag, t.Score from tablename as t inner join cte as c 
on t.teamtag=c.teamtag order by c.sum desc, t.score desc
```

Comment: This one code doesn't assume summ of particular team score, am i right?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dbms supports window functions

```
select PlrName, TeamTag, Score
from (
    select PlrName, TeamTag, Score, sum(Score) over (partition by TeamTag) ms
    from tablename ) t
order by ms desc, TeamTag, Score desc
```

**EDIT** changed `max()` to `sum()` as OP refined the problem explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I made it like this, but feel little uncomfortable about sql :D

```
    SELECT * FROM `Playerbase` as T1
    JOIN
    (SELECT TeamTag, SUM(Score) AS Sum FROM `Playerbase` GROUP BY TeamTag ORDER BY Sum DESC) AS T2
    ON T2.TeamTag = T1.TeamTag
```

Didn't make what i was trying to, but anyway thanks for answers. They helped me to understand a bit more :D